# vite: Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "react-slick" from "XXX.tsx". Does the file exist?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vue.js, vite

Error occures when i try to load the @types/react-slick package in my react typescript app.

```
yarn add @types/react-slick
```

The code does not show any error in the editor and referes to the right path. The package has been installed. Not really sure how to handle this issue as similar questions only refer to internal imports.

> vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
   plugins: [react()],
})
```

> tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "ESNext",
"useDefineForClassFields": true,
"lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
"allowJs": false,
"skipLibCheck": true,
"esModuleInterop": false,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"strict": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"module": "ESNext",
"moduleResolution": "Node",
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"isolatedModules": true,
"noEmit": true,
"jsx": "react-jsx"
},
"include": ["src/**/*"],
"references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's because the value of moduleResolution is in lowercase? In your case, it should be "node" instead "Node"? BTW, I'm guessing...